# embed chat script in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a javascript script that inserts an online chat into my site, my intention is to insert it into my app.component.html but when I insert it directly there, it is not displayed.

Is there an option to import my script and have it embedded inside a tag?

at the moment:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

//not work
<script>
    //script code
</script>
```

in my index.html it works fine, but here I have a problem since it doesn't display well in android and therefore I need to embed it in the app.component.html

```
<body>
      <script>
          //script code....  
      </script>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

i want:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<div id="widgetItem"></div> //insert my script from app.component.ts
```

Is there a mechanism to embed my script in that tag? or embed it after the ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ElementRef` and `Renderer2` from `@angular/core` to dynamically create and insert the script element:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const script = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    
    const scriptCode = `
      // Your script code goes here
    `;
    const scriptContent = this.renderer.createText(scriptCode);
    this.renderer.appendChild(script, scriptContent);

    const widgetItem = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#widgetItem');
    this.renderer.appendChild(widgetItem, script);
  }
}
```